# Cosmos db order by on field which is actually numeric but contains data as string

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In my cosmos database, I have few records with a particular field called durationInMillSecs. This durationInMillSecs field contains values like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21. in string format e.g.

```
{
"id": "{GUID},
"durationInMillSecs": "1",
 ....other fields
},
{
"id": "{GUID},
"durationInMillSecs": "2",
 ....other fields
}
```

But these values are actually integers.

If I apply order by on this column then it is treated as string and results are sort in order
1, 10, 11, 2, 20, 21, 3....and so on. The query i used is as follows

`select * from c order by c.durationInMillSecs`

I want to write a query in cosmosdb which can order than based on their numerical value.

1. I tried StringToNumber function but it is not working in Order by clause.
2. I tried traditional way of first ordering by length and then order by column but it is not working too.

   > SELECT
   > columnName
   > FROM
   > yourtable
   > ORDER BY
   > LENGTH( columnName ),
   > columnName;

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be necessary to have an index on the properties you want to sort on, and [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/order-by) states:

> The Azure Cosmos DB query runtime supports sorting against a property name and not against computed properties"

I'm no expert with Cosmos, so there may be a workaround, but I'm afraid I don't know it. It may be necessary to sort on the client side instead.

Comment: This is correct. It is not possible to do a numerical sort on data stored as a string. Data stored as a string is indexed as a string. Currently, the only way to mitigate this is to sort client-side or create a new numeric property.

Comment: This is actually code which is running on production and it is not possible to add numeric property in records now. I am not sure how efficient will be client side sorting